# trying to open full text when webscraping using selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to open the full text on a page when using selenium.

I got the following code:

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver as wb
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

```
webD=wb.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
webD.get('https://www.flashscore.com/')

webD.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
webD.implicitly_wait(2) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
webD.find_element_by_id('onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()

matchpages = webD.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "preview-ico.icon--preview")
Open_full_text =  webD.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "previewShowMore.showMore")

for matchpages in matchpages:
    matchpages.click()
time.sleep(5)

for Open_full_text in Open_full_text:
    Open_full_text.click()
```

However, When I try to let this script click on the open full text button, it does not open up completely.

What is the reason for this, or how can this be adjusted? Is it ok to use the for loop in this scenario, or do I have to use another method?

Thanks very much!

Comment: `(By.CLASS_NAME, "preview-ico.icon--preview")` doesn't matches any element. Can you update the question with the manual steps you are trying to automate?

Comment: It does. However, 'Open_full_text =  webD.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "previewShowMore.showMore")' does not seem to match an element. When you delete this linei t should work. Could it be, because of how the for-loop is applied?